# Print awk results on a new line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Is there an option I can use in this command to return each result on a new line instead of just separated by a space?

```
echo $(ps ax | awk '/usr/ {print $5}')
```

Comment: Drop the pointless `echo $()` part of that which is eating your newlines. Just use `ps ax | awk '/usr/ {print $5}'`.

Comment: This? `ps ax | awk '/usr/ {print $5}'`.

Comment: OP, why did you use `echo $(...)` in the first place? what did you think you were achieving with this `echo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do it is simply:

`ps ax | awk '/usr/ {print $5}'`

If you want to keep your original form with `echo` (but I think it's pointless), then you'd have to quote the subshell result:

`echo "$(ps ax | awk '/usr/ {print $5}')"`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{while("ps ax"|getline){if($5~/^\/usr\//){print $5}}}'
```

alternative approach

```
 ps -ax|awk '{if($5~/^\/usr\//){print $5}}'
```

Comment: Why do you use `echo "$(...)"` instead of `...` (thus `ps -ax` before the pipe.

Comment: @ CommuSoft thank you for bringing this to my attention..i was trying to work on my speed...answer edited